# Итерация по словарю с словарями

Tags: python, search

У меня есть словаря типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно пройтись по нему и получить все ключи

Вся проблема в том, что уровень вложености может быть разный к примеру больше 10

Answer (score 1):

```
adj={1:1,
    2:2,
    3:{
        "3.1":"3.2",
        "3.3":{
            "3.3.1":"3.3.1",
            "3.3.2":"3.3.2"
              },
        },
    4:{
        "4.1":"4.1",
        "4.2":"4.2"
    }

}

def alin(adj):
    for a, b in adj.items():
        print(f"{a} : {b}")#убрать b если нужны только ключи
        if type(b)==dict:
            print(b)#убрать если хочешь видеть только ключи и значения 
            alin(b)
alin(adj)
```

Чуть доработать под свои нужды, вместо принтов добавлять в список и тд. Оставляйте только принт `a` чтобы видеть ключи